# ReactNative Button onPress target getAttribute not accessible in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, attributes

I use TypeScript in ReactNative to access Button target.getAttribute("data-code") but getAttribute is not accessible in onPress event. How can I reference target type? I googled around the internet but neither solution helped.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Button,
  GestureResponderEvent,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const _onPressButton = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
    Alert.alert(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-code'));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          data-code="note1"
          onPress={_onPressButton}
          title="Light (On)"
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          data-code="Note2"
          onPress={_onPressButton}
          title="light (OFF)"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please try this

 

    import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
    import {
      Alert,
      TouchableOpacity,
      GestureResponderEvent,
      StyleSheet,
      View,
    } from 'react-native';
    
    const App = () => {
    
      const [light, setLight] = useState(false)
    
      const onClickLight =()=>{
        setLight(!light)
}

useEffect(()=>{
let data_code = '';
if(light){
   data_code = 'note1'
}else{
   data_code = 'Note2'
}
fetch(`youURL/${data_code}`).then(()=>{
 //your response
})
},[light])    

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClickLight()}>
              <Text>Light{light ? "(ON)":"(OFF)"}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      buttonContainer: {
        margin: 20,
      },
    });
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Error message: E ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

Comment: can you provide screen shot

Comment: screen shot posted above. It is a react native Button component and not HTMLButtonElement. Is this a matter?

Comment: please check this above code

Comment: I need data-code as string for parameter of a fetch.

Comment: just change code please check

Comment: I have different codes for more then two buttons. Each has parameters, so not just 2 state must handled.

Comment: I refigured my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109138/reactnative-htmlbuttonelement-gives-error-at-emulator

Comment: You are directly invoking the handler here: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={onClickLight()}>`.  Your curly brackets are off, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my android emulator screen shot [image: Android emulator screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

interface MyButtonProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  dataCode: string;
}
class MyButton extends React.Component<
  MyButtonProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>,
  {}
> {
  render() {
    return <button {...this.props} />;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const _onPressButton = (event: any) => {
    let params: string = (event.currentTarget as MyButton).props.dataCode;
    fetch(`http://191.162.10.101/switch?${params}`);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <MyButton
          dataCode="note1"
          onClick={_onPressButton}
          title="Light (ON)"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
  },
});

export default App;
```

But this happend:

[image: button must be a function]

Comment: you need to pass Button Not button